# How to set sbt dependencies correctly?

Tags: playframework-2.0, sbt

I'm a beginner of the play framework 2(2.2.1) and want to use open csv inside it.
I searched for a maven repository, then add a line bellow inside the file **build.sbt**

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "net.sf.opencsv" % "opencsv" % "2.3" from "http://central.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/opencsv/opencsv/2.3/opencsv-2.3.pom"
)
```

I'm sure that the pom file locates at

```
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/opencsv/opencsv/2.3/opencsv-2.3.pom
```

but the play console says that it search for

```
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/opencsv/opencsv_2.10_0.13/2.3/opencsv-2.3.pom
```

then it fails.

How can I use the  library correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have added the line to the `project/build.sbt` file. The way sbt works is kind of confusing. The `/project/build.sbt` file defines the dependencies of the *build* itself. That is why it looks for a dependency that matches your scala version (2.10) as well as your sbt version (0.13).

To add a dependency to your project rather than your build (I know it is confusing), you would have to add the line either to `/build.sbt` or `/project/Build.scala` depending of which kind of Build definition you use (See [this sbt doc entry](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.1/docs/Getting-Started/Basic-Def.html) for explanation)

Comment: Thanks very much to your response!

Comment: Downloading seems successful! But importing net.sf.opencsv in /app/Global.java causes error because it doesn't exist. I know this is the different question but I'm happy if you give me an advise. thx.

Comment: Looking at the [JavaDoc](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html) it looks like you got the package name wrong. It is `au.com.bytecode.opencsv` not `net.sf.opencsv`. The group and artifact id of a dependency don't have to necessarily match the package names.